# What to do about the vmmap process in Mac OS X always hogging the CPU?

Tags: macos, memory, virtual-memory, memory-management, macos-highsierra

I am running Mac OS X 10.13.5 High Sierra, and I have always had my Activity Monitor up.

My computer would every now and then freeze for a few seconds completely and then act normal again. When this happens, I have noticed that it is because the "vmmap" process hogging up like 99.8% of the CPU.

Is there anything I can do to prevent vmmap from doing that without having to restart my computer every time? I know this must have something to do with the virtual memory management and possibly having too many page faults?

When I go to the Memory section in Activity Monitor, I see:

```
Physical Memory: 16.00GB
Memory Used: 15.23 GB
Cached Files: 772.2MB
Swap used: 8.37 GB

App Memory: 4.14 GB
Wired Memory: 8.18 GB
Compressed: 3.36GB
```

Is the swap file too big?